# Identify this excreta!

Tags: species-identification, zoology, excreta

A picture is worth a thousand words!

It's about 1.3cm (1/2") long. We rented a basement and I found this on a machine that was moved in a bit earlier.

I would like to know if there are any mice, rats, etc that could have come in.

We are on the island of Malta, in the Mediterranean sea.
The basement is below a shop that used to sell AC units and the basement was used as a storage. The walls have gaping holes where cables and pipes go in and out, etc. Clearly industrial and not made for the customer to see.

[image]

Comment: Where are you located? Are you in the city, the country, ...?

Comment: I added more details in the post.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to identify a species based solely on the length and appearance of its feces

Comment: Definitely too big for mice (max 7mm). Could be a rat or a bat (hopefully for you the latter). What was the width? And did you see any clear renmants in the poop? Like beetle shields, hair or plant fibers?

Comment: There was nothing around, just that poop and a clean surface around, but this is in a basement we just got. The climate is hot and humid. The only insects we've seen are large cockroaches.

Answer (score -2):

Bat is the other basement creature that comes to mind. It looks like a match as explained in this and several other videos - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=897Fb9ndids

[image]

Comment: I just looked at photos of bat poop and they look more bulky, while this one is thin and long.